# Bound cmd as default program for JS files

Tags: file, cmd, command, prompt

I have the following problem. For some reason (I wanted to try something) I set the command prompt (C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe) as the default program (right click JS-file, properties, opens with -> change... ).

Now, for some reason, I can't change it back to an other program. The option of doing so in the file options has disappeared. Any way to change it back to normal?

Thanks,
Ruben.

EDIT: 
output of reg query hkcr\jsfile\shell /s:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\shell
>       (Default)    REG_SZ    Open
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\shell\Edit
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\shell\Edit\Command
>       (Default)    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe %1
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\shell\Edit with Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\shell\Edit with Adobe Dreamweaver
>   CS5.5\Command
>       (Default)    REG_SZ    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5 \Dreamweaver.exe","%1"
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\shell\Open
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\shell\Open\Command
>       (Default)    REG_SZ    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5 \dreamweaver.exe","%1"
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\shell\Open\ddeexec
>       (Default)    REG_SZ
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\shell\Open2
>       (Default)    REG_SZ    Open &with Command Prompt
>       MUIVerb    REG_SZ    @C:\Windows\System32\wshext.dll,-4511
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\shell\Open2\Command
>       (Default)    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\System32\CScript.exe "%1" %*
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\shell\Print
>
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\shell\Print\Command
>       (Default)    REG_SZ    C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe /p %1

Answer (score 1):

Open a `cmd` box and use `ASSOC` and `FTYPE`.

Output on my Windows 7 system:

```
C:\Windows\System32>assoc .js
.js=JSFile

C:\Windows\System32>ftype jsfile
jsfile=C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe "%1" %*
```

Using `ASSOC`, you can find out which filetype is associated to `.js`
Assuming "`JSFile`", you can use "`ftype jsfile`" to find the command defined as default for JSFile. "`ftype /?`" explains how to change the command.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but even when I change it there, nothing happens. Same thing when I right click a JS file -> open with -> choose default program...
I can choose one, but when I double click the file in explorer, cmd will still open.

Comment: update your question with the output of `reg query hkcr\jsfile\shell /s`.

Comment: Your JSfiles are (still) opened by Adobe Dreamweaver rather than by cmd.exe. You might not have sufficient rights to change the settings. Start the cmd.exe mentioned in my answer "as Administrator".

Comment: I was able to change the setting, and there it says they are opened by dreamweaver. But they keep opening with cmd. No matter what setting I put there. Already tried that, no luck.

Comment: This was the only method I've tried that successfully allowed me to change the program that opens .js files. I have Win 10 with VS 2017 and IIS installed, and none of the registry editing techniques worked. One command at an administrator prompt, though, and the issues is resolved: `ftype JSFile="C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" "%1"`. Thank you!